# Stored Procedure Error Records Capture in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am merging the data from Source to Target via Stored Procedures in Snowflake.
But there are some rejections of records while merging.
How to capture those rejected records in a table or file?

Comment: Please provide additional detail. At a minimum that would include the merge statement SQL text, the table DDLs, sample input data and sample of rows that need to be handled as rejected.

Comment: Looks like you want to identify the rows that failed to insert, one way you can identify the records that were not inserted by doing a MINUS between the source table and the target table.